# How to download pdf from html embed tag without src rendered by javascript in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, web-scraping, download

I am going to download pdf from html page.

The page structure is following.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="a.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

`a.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>this.document.location = "pubs/document-238727.PDF";</script>
</head>

</html>
```

inspect view of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="a.html">
            #document
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
                <embed
                    name="289740873" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="182D67B1A56A055A2F879042870BB4E0">
            </head>

            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am going to download this pdf file of `embed` tag.
I have tried in several ways but didn't yet.

Comment: It is a bit hard to tell without a better context on how the underlying Javascript works, but in general, you can try to find out how to invoke the javascript and then execute it via ```driver.execute_script``` function.

Comment: I have just found the solution. @Frederickcjo is right. The important thing is to get the link to the pdf file. I have run `driver.execute_script('return document.location.href')` in the frame. It worked well.

Comment: Congrats @LeThanhThai. Glad that you resolved it.